# Grunt 7z compression addon

Tags: open-source, javascript, node.js

There is a [Node.js LZMA](https://www.npmjs.org/package/lzma-purejs) addon. However I cannot find any [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) wrappers for that or any other LZMA libraries; so I'm wondering if anyone knows any?

Requirements:

- Open source
- Grunt 0.4.4+ compatible

Comment: You could use [grunt-execute](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-execute) in conjunction with the Node.js LZMA addon which you found.